# How to change the text of a button with a method?

Tags: c#

I need to change the text of a button and I tried doing it with a method with two string parameters.

```
public void setQuestion(String a, String b)
{
    a = b;
}
setQuestion(btnA.Text, "Hey" );
```

When I run the method, it doesn´t change the text. But if I write it like this

```
btnA.Text = "Hey"
```

it works just fun. I am curious why the method doesnt change the text of the button

I know the method is useless, I just want to know why it doesnt work that way

Comment: You are changing a local variable that only refers to a string, it has no knowledge of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following *would* work, although I'm not exactly sure on the data type of your 'button'. You need to pass in the reference to the object rather than an arbitrary string value.

```
public void setQuestion(Button a, String b)
{
    a.Text = b;
}
setQuestion(btnA, "Hey" );
```

Comment: btnA.Text is only a property of the button btnA that is passed by reference to the method (i.e., setQuestion(Button a, String b) )

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change because nothing inside your method refers to the button or anything related to it. Logically, when you write `btnA.Text = "Hey"`, it changes, because you are addressing the property.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are changing 2 local variables. To be more specific, you change 2 local strings, even though you want to set the question of a button a to the string b. (Btw, please use better naming) So what you should do is you change the String a to a Button a. Now you can just change the string in the button e.g. with a.Text = b.

In a nutshell, just write:

```
public void setQuestion(Button a, String b)//Button instead of String
{
    a = b;
}
setQuestion(btnA.Text, "Hey" );
```

Hope I could help, good luck and have a nice day.